# How to store in one table an Entity composed by others Entity with Hibernate?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc, hibernate-mapping

I am using SpringMVC + Hibernate and I am facing a problem that I struggle to solve. 
The situation is as follow :

I have this Entity :

```
@Entity
@Table( name = "T_inscription" )
public class T_inscription implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
  private Long           id_inscription;

  @Valid
  private Identite       identite;

  @Valid
  private ParamConnexion paramConnexion;
//........
}
```

This class :

```
public class Identite implements Serializable {

  @Size( min = 2 )
  @NotBlank
  @Pattern( regexp = "[\\p{L}\\p{Alpha} -]*" )
  @Column( name = "nom" )
  private String  nom;

  @Size( min = 2 )
  @NotBlank
  @Pattern( regexp = "[\\p{L}\\p{Alpha} -]*" )
  @Column( name = "prenom" )
  private String  prenom;
//....
}
```

And this one :

```
public class ParamConnexion implements Serializable {

  @Pattern( regexp = "[\\p{L}\\p{Alnum}-_]*" )
  @Size( min = 2 )
  @Transient
  private String                 identifiant;

  @Pattern( regexp = "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\."
        + "[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*"
        + "@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?" )
  @Column( name = "email" )
  private String                 email;
//.....
}
```

My table "T_inscription" contains these fields : "id_inscription","nom", "prenom", "identifiant", "email", etc...

My question is, how can I proceed to save the attributes of the classes "Identite" and "ParamConnexion" in the table "T_inscription" ?

I don't want to create a table per class. Is there a way to do this ?

I tried and I got this exeption : `Unknown column 'identite' in 'field list'`

It's normal because I do not have this field in my table and I don't want to create it, I just want to get the properties of "Identite".

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two non-entity classes must be annotated with `@Embeddable`. The fields `identite` and `paramConnexion` must be annotated with `Embedded` Refer to the javadoc of those two annotations for more information.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is there a list of all annotations with their descriptions somewhere?

Comment: Yes. In the javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/). And in the specs (http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/index.html).

Comment: I noticed that I had already downloaded the JSR338 pdf but I didn't know where to look for what I had needed. I am french and do not really master the english so it is quite difficult for me to find the required information in this kind of datasheet. Thanks again.